# Is it possible to make a hash function that sorts a dictionary

Tags: c, hash

I thought about a good hash function that automatically sorts a bunch of words.

Maybe it could be done by the sum of all the ASCII value of each letter.

```
int hash(char *str){

  int i,value=0;

  for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    value=value+(str[i]%97);

  return value;
}
```

But then this would cause a lot of collisions because, for example: 3+5=8+0=7+1=6+2 and so on...

Is it even possible to a hash function to do this? If so, how is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, in this way "bz" will come after "za"..

Comment: This is a bad idea because an ordered value space contradicts the purpose of hashing. Do both things separately...

Comment: Well, consider this. For this to work, your hash function would have to produce a different value for any two different strings. If a string is made up out of 8 bit characters, how many different 4 character strings are there? How about 8? Are you seeing the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is no.
Your hash could take the first four character and interpret them as an integer. That' would be a has function of sorts, but a degenerate case.

The basic idea of hashing is that you get what looks like a random value from the data, and changing just one bit of the data changes the hash totally (so each bit of the data contributes to each bit of the hash).

There are many hash functions available.